# SFMC Cloud Page Load Time

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We have added a new Cloud Page using a SFMC Template. Load time is fine at about 1 - 2 secs. We then copied the Cloud Page and added a few anchor links and the load time has increased to approximately 8 - 10 secs.

Has anyone here experienced a similar issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although not directly an answer to your question, this might help - you will be able to see the load time of each asset on your CloudPage:

Open the CloudPage in Chrome and use Chrome developer tools to measure the load time.

> 1. Open the CloudPage in Chrome, then right-click and select inspect or hit F12 to open the console
> 2. In the console, click on the Network tab
> 3. In the top right corner, you will see 'No throttling' - click on it and select an option (I usually choose Fast 3G or Slow 3G)
> 4. Refresh the page and watch the page load

You will then see what takes the most time to load. Usually deleting unnecessary CSS and JavaScript helps.

Comment: That's very help. Thanks